# Hive - Out of Memory Exception

Tags: hive, beeswax

which results in MR job.  The MR job runs successfully, but when beeswax tries to render the result then I get an OOM Exception.

I was wondering if there is a configuration setting to help me get passed this issue.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:2694)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:203)
    at java.nio.HeapCharBuffer.toString(HeapCharBuffer.java:561)
    at java.nio.CharBuffer.toString(CharBuffer.java:1201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.decode(Text.java:394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.decode(Text.java:371)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.toString(Text.java:273)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.buildJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:280)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.getJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:220)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.DelimitedJSONSerDe.serializeField(DelimitedJSONSerDe.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe.serialize(LazySimpleSerDe.java:427)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ListSinkOperator.processOp(ListSinkOperator.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:474)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.pushRow(FetchOperator.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchTask.fetch(FetchTask.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.getResults(Driver.java:1474)
    at com.cloudera.beeswax.BeeswaxServiceImpl$RunningQueryState.materializeResults(BeeswaxServiceImpl.java:434)
    at com.cloudera.beeswax.BeeswaxServiceImpl$RunningQueryState.fetch(BeeswaxServiceImpl.java:543)
    at com.cloudera.beeswax.BeeswaxServiceImpl$5.run(BeeswaxServiceImpl.java:986)
    at com.cloudera.beeswax.BeeswaxServiceImpl$5.run(BeeswaxServiceImpl.java:981)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1438)
    at com.cloudera.beeswax.BeeswaxServiceImpl.doWithState(BeeswaxServiceImpl.java:772)
    at com.cloudera.beeswax.BeeswaxServiceImpl.fetch(BeeswaxServiceImpl.java:980)
    at com.cloudera.beeswax.api.BeeswaxService$Processor$fetch.getResult(BeeswaxService.java:987)
    at com.cloudera.beeswax.api.BeeswaxService$Processor$fetch.getResult(BeeswaxService.java:971)
    at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
    at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:244)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
```

**Update**
I increased the memory settings in cloudera manager but no cigar.  After restarting the service the first time I run the query it works.  The second time I run it fails:

- Hue - Beeswax Server (Default) / Resource Management - Java Heap Size
  of Beeswax Server in Bytes [1 Gib]
- Hive - Gateway (Default) / Resource Management - Client Java Heap Size in Bytes [1 Gib]
- Hive - HiveServer2
  (Default) / Resource Management -  Java Heap Size of HiveServer2 in
  Bytes [1 Gib]

Answer (score 0):

There are three -Xmx that you can play with (increase) - client java, Hive Serever 2 and Hive Meta Store Server. I guess you're hitting one of these limtits.

Comment: Thanks @Ruslan.  I guess it is the client, how would I set the client xmx for beeswax?

Comment: Are you using Cloudera distribution? If so, navigate to Hive -> Configuration  -> type in "xmx" into Search box. First option will be "Client Java Heap Size in Bytes", it defaults to 1Gb I believe. See if increasing this helps.

Comment: I tried it but didn't really work.  I updated the question...thanks

Comment: oh, bummer. "After restarting the service the first time I run the query it works. The second time I run it fails" - memory leak? Try opening case with Cloudera, they're usually very good with this type of problems.